# Invalid resource directory name "font" Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I just upgraded Visual Studio for mac to support Android 8 / api 26. I updated the AppCompat library to 26.1 to use the new font folder in the Resources directory of my Android project. Now when I try to compile I get "Invalid resource directory name" for path "obj/Debug/res/font" APT0000.

[image: Error message]

[image: Resources folder]

[image: Xamarin android version]

Comment: How about adding fonts in the Assets/font directory?

Comment: @MilanG That is how did it originally but since appcompat version 26 it is possible to add them as a resource. This is how I want to do it.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_7_-_fonts/#Fonts_as_a_Resource

Comment: Please ensure that your `build-tools` matches the API level you are compiling against. In this case, you need to use `build-tools` 26 or higher if targeting Oreo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First always check out the latest xamarin documentation about new features.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/introduction-to-oreo/

I quickly created a new xamarin android project and added two textviews with diffrent fonts:

[image: Test App]

My solution looks as the following:

[image: Solution]

I usually try to avoid capital letters in resource names as the android studio complains about it.

Main Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:text="Pacifico example text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico" />

  <TextView
  android:text="Roboto light example text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think that you do not use the latest platform to build.
Check that you use the latest platform (Oreo) to build the application.

Answer (score 14):

For me the solution was to remove all the old Android SDK Build Tools from the SDK Manager. Now I only have for api level 26 and 27 installed and it works.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me, didn't have to add new Tools versions, but had to delete all old ones (< 26)

Answer (score 1):

My resolution for this problem was to add the following line in the root of the project file

```
<PropertyGroup><AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>27.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion></PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

the right answer is in 
[invalid resource directory](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106768/invalid-resource-directory-name-obj-debug-res-fonts).
you must add fonts in assets/fonts and clean Rebuild