# Invalid resource directory name obj\Debug\res menu.png

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, resources, png

I try to do a hamburger menu, but I have an exception when I try to compile the solution. I'm developing a Xamarin Cross Platform Application.

I have the exception:

obj\Debug\res menu.png project.Android invalid resource directory name

And the code when I use the menu.png file is:

```
Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null;
```

I add the png file as an already exists element on "Resources" folder at iOS and Android project. I check that the file exists in the folder and I follow this steps to try to fix it, but it doesn't work for me:

[Invalid resource directory name "font" Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436465/invalid-resource-directory-name-font-xamarin-android)

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I fix it! I deleted the png file on Android resources and it worked correctly. I suppose I import twice the file (on portable solution and on Android solution) and that makes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue by adding build tools version 27.0.3 to my sdk location/build-tools.
check the required build tools version in obj/debug/[compile-version]/build.props